# Send image position across multiple mobile aspect ratio in a multi player game

Tags: android, mobile, swift, game-development

I am developing a multi player network based virtual pet game where Player 1 can select game assets ( images ) and position them anywhere on the screen , Scale the image , rotate the image. Once the player submits their game state on the multiple player game instance,  I would like the player 2 on another Mobile aspect ratio to be able to see the game assets positions of the player 1's virtual pet exactly in same positions even if they are using a mobile device of different aspect ratio/ resolution.

I want to pass (X, Y , height , width , angle)  of the player 1's each game assets position to player's 2 device when the player1 submits his/her game screen state . I would like some help reference  as to how the player 2's mobile device would render its UI game screen  to present the player1's  game asset positions.

Would like the reference to this in Swift & Andriod. I prefer not to use any game engines.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: What I am trying to do is something like this. In the following link you will see the player 1 is maintaining a Virtual dog , the player can position the dress, feed the virtual dog with game assets and I would like to send these details to Player2 so player2 could see what the player 1 has done with his/her game assets for the virtual dog. Link in another comment...

Comment: This link is here   https://www.google.com/search?q=virtual+pet&biw=1241&bih=672&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=YMWWVKeRMYGxggTg7YHABw&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg#facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=sbyAKWVAcdgkDM%253A%3BCyUfHOKWVmahyM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.cutehomepets.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2010%252F09%252Fvirtual-pet-clubs.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.cutehomepets.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2010%252F09%252F%3B600%3B401

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to have a consistent scene size across all devices. Say the scene is 2000 x 2000, then the only thing that is different on different devices is the portion of the scene that is visible at any given time. From this, it is very easy to get the coordinates of an asset it this scene because you don't make the origin relative to the device, but rather to the coordinates of the scene. Another way to do this is by percentages. Doing this, you say something like x = xOnScreen / totalScreenWidth and y = yOnScreen / totalScreenHeight. Then When you're on a different device just multiply that devices totalScreenWidth by the percentage to get the scaled location on screen. The first method is the best way to maintain aspect ratios.